# TypeScript transpiles types in generic to static types

Tags: typescript

I have a namespace that can be extended by the user

```
declare global {
     namespace Firebinder {
          export namespace Firestore {
               export interface CollectionTypes {}
          }
          export namespace Auth {
               export interface CustomClaims {}
          }
     }
}
```

upon transpiling TypeScript renders the declarations of this code snipper as following:

```
// Source code
const useCollection = <V, T extends string,>(collectionId: T): CollectionReference<T extends keyof Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes ? Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes[T] : V> => {...}

// Declaration File Emitted by TS
declare const useCollection: <V, T extends string>(collectionId: T) => CollectionReference<T extends never ? Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes[T] : V>;
```

As it changes, `<T extends keyof Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes` to `<T extends never`, when the user extends the interface `Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes` in their own code, it won't be recognized by TS.

How can I fix this problem so that upon compilation `extends keyof Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes` won't turn into `extends never`

Comment: How to make it so upon compilation `extends keyof Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes` won't turn into `extends never`

Comment: @jcalz oh sorry the Keys part was left out of some testing. I fixed that part back how it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using `declare` in my TypeScript code

```
declare let useCollection: <V, T extends string>(collectionId: T) => CollectionReference<T extends keyof Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes ? Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes[T] : V>;

useCollection = <V, T extends string>(collectionId: T): CollectionReference<T extends keyof Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes ? Firebinder.Firestore.CollectionTypes[T] : V> => {...}
```

Comment: Looks like a missing TS feature, see [ms/TS#33254](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33254) and [ms/TS#42853](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42853).  For now the workaround is that you have to manually declare your function type (which seems to be what you did in your answer).  Do you want to edit this info into your answer so that interested parties will find the relevant GitHub issues?